# Xcode cdtool can not compile issue

Tags: ios, core-data, compilation, core-data-migration, build-error

I added version to my `DataModel` and got "cdtool can not compile".

Did anyone experience similar problem? and what is "cdtool" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I my data model contains many-to-many relationship without the inverse of it.

From Apple documentation:

> You must define many-to-many relationships in both directions—that is,
>   you must specify two relationships, each being the inverse of the
>   other. You can’t just define a to-many relationship in one direction
>   and try to use it as a many-to-many. If you do, you will end up with
>   referential integrity problems.